# XSLT/XPATH : document() on XHTML file returns nothing

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to concat/filter a number of XHTML files based upon an XML index file containing a reference to the root name of each XHTML file. The XSLT stylesheet is applied on the XML index file.

I validated the process with XML files instead of XHTML files.

But when I use XHTML files instead of XML files the document() instruction applied to my XHTML files returns nothing.

According to posts I read on the forum, this is probable a problem of namespaces but I did not manage to make it work according to what I understood.

In the XSLT file, I added :
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" and the h: prefixes
thinking it would help but it did not. My understanding is this area is very little at this stage.

I copied the full header of the actual XHTML files in the example used below : mails.xhml.

Thank you for help.

The XML index file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mail_list>
    <file name="mailx.xhtml" />
    ...
</mail_list>
```

The mailx.xhtml file model :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="text/css" xml:space="preserve"/>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    </head>

    <body class="entry">
        <p class="name">first_name last_name</p>
        <p class="address">first_name.last_name@examplex.com</p>
    </body>
</html
```

Ths XSLT file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

exclude-result-prefixes="h">

<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/mail_list/file">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@name)/h:entry" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h:entry">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h:name">Name: <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h:address">Email Address: <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Simply use `<xsl:copy-of select="document(@name)"/>` to check whether the document functions loads the document. As for selecting elements in the XHTML namespace, neither XHTML as defined by the W3C nor your sample has any elements named `entry` or `name` or `address, you only have elements with a class attribute value of e.g. `entry`.

Comment: <xsl:copy-of select="document(@name)"/> was successful and your questioning was absolutely correct. Thank you Martin. Here below Mads provided the full correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are matching on `h:entry` but that file does not have any elements named `entry`.

There is a `<body class="entry">` which is a `body` element with a `@class` attribute with a value of `entry` that is a child of the `h:html` element: `/h:html/h:body[@class='entry']`

So, change

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document(@name)/h:html/h:body[@class='entry']" />
```

or more generically:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document(@name)//*[@class='entry']" />
```

And then change:

```
<xsl:template match="h:entry">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

to either:

```
<xsl:template match="h:body[@class='entry']">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

or more generically:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@class='entry']">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

The same applies to the templates matching `h:name` and `h:address` instead of elements that have `@class` values.

When I run the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    
    exclude-result-prefixes="h">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/mail_list/file">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@name)//*[@class='entry']" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[@class='entry']">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[@class='name']">Name: <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[@class='address']">Email Address: <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

against an input XML file that has the `mailx.xhtml` in the same directory, it produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>Name: first_name last_nameEmail Address: first_name.last_name@examplex.com
```

Comment: Double check that the `mailx.xhtml` file is in the same directory as the XML file being transformed, that the file is readable, etc. Also maybe try running a transform directly against that `mailx.xhtml` as a quick test that it is readable, parsable, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much Mads, you were dead on. It was the XPath problem as you stated at the beginning of your post. This one was in my zone of knowledge but did not see it. What about the namespaces ? Is that the correct way to handle XHTML files ?

Comment: Yes, if the XML (or XHTML) has element bound to a namespace, then in your XSLT you either need to declare that namespace and use a namespace-prefix in your XPaths, or use the more generic means of matching such as wildcards for the namespace i.e. `/*:html/*:body` in place of `/h:html/h:body`, or match very generically on elements and filter by `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()` inside of a predicate.

Comment: But in this case, you don't seem to care about the element names and namespaces, only matching on the attribute values, so the generic `*` match on element is likely enough (for what you have shown)